# Get all CDI beans

Tags: javabeans, jndi, cdi, lookup, resolver

I want to retrieve all CDI beans from container as map which bean names as keys and beans as values. How could I achieve this?

I need this to add CDI beans to thymeleaf expression resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a portable extension and this to the `ProcessAnnotatedType` event. Then have it look for types which have the `@Named` annotation and add it to a static map on your class, or some other class.

Comment: Ok, It works:) But I have one more question: I will be asking for this map of beans on every request, in extension I should create map of beans names and beans instances (gained from BeanManager in extension class) and return this map on every request, or should I create a map of beans names and beans classes and ask bean manager for beans instances on every request?

Comment: Ok, I discover that I need to ask BeanManager for beans in every request.
Thanks a lot for help:)